# Java equivalent for Apex classes

Tags: apex, force.com, java, android

I am looking for Java equivalent classes for some of the Apex classes like `Blob`, `EncodingUtil`, `Crypto`. I need these to connect and authenticate with salesforce making an API call.

I am creatingn a SalesForce Android app where I need to achieve the following in java.

Apex code:

```
Blob signatureBlob = Blob.valueOf("xxxxxxx");

String signature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', signatureBlob));
```

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SFSE. Can you explain why do you need this, and how and where you want to implement this? Are you sure this S&A site is the right place for this?  maybe Stackexchange?

Comment: This appears to be in no way related to salesforce1. Please only use tags that are related to the subject of your question.

Comment: this could be clarified in the question, but presumably the question is related to generating signatures in java that can be verified in apex & visa-versa, which would make it on topic (IMO) for this site.

Comment: I am working on a salesforce Android app in which, to create/fetch Licenses, I need to make a portal call 1st. There I need this MD5 signature to be appended with API. I got that above code from apex but could not get equivalent classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the [hexadecimal (base 16) representation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_EncodingUtil_convertToHex.htm) for the [MD5 hash for your input string](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003698&language=en_US)?

Have a look at [Generate MD5 hash in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java?rq=1) and [From string to hex MD5 hash and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023122/from-string-to-hex-md5-hash-and-back). There is an answer there from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3023151/54026) that uses Hex.encodeHexString from the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) to do the Hex encoding of the MD5 hash.

```
// For MessageDigest
import java.security.*;
// My Java is a bit rusty. I think this will get us access to the Hex namespace
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*: 

//..

string yourString = "xxxxxxx";
byte[] bytesOfMessage = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);

String signature = Hex.encodeHexString(thedigest);
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for d answer. will try and let u know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I could not get 'encodeHexString' method so had to do 'char[] signature = Hex.encodeHex(thedigest);
String finalSignature = String.valueOf(signature);'